# Is it possible force Qt to call paintEvent after other Qt components are drawn?

Tags: c++, qt

I've a class that extends QWidget and contains a QLabel (*lblBackground*). I've overriden paintEvent function too.

I want to draw something on top of *lblBackground* however paintEvent method is called before the QLabel is drawn. Thus my custom drawings are overwritten.

Is there a way to change drawing order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Painting the children on top of their parent is the common thing to do. That being said you could try one of the following options:

1. extend QLabel itself to paint whatever you want
2. try to set the `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` flag on the `QLabel` and having an alpha channel, so that the underlying parent (`QWidget`) would shine through
3. if you are only using the `QLabel` to paint some background, maybe you can get rid of it and paint the desired background first thing in the QWidget's `paintEvent()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use label as a background then just create your custom widget as a child of your label. May be split some window frame related tasks if any (to be implemented as a parent of the label) and drawing/controls/etc (to be child of the label).